# Upload image with Ajax in M2

Tags: magento2, product-images, ajax, image-upload

In my custom module i am trying to upload images. I am able to upload images with the help of this link

> https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-upload-image-in-magento2/

But is there any way where we can preview the image before uploading to server in M2. Like

> isAjax = true

Do we have any possibility in M2 to make functionality  same like

> catalog/product_gallery/upload

Comment: did you get any solution can you share?